# Check if a specific array element contains a whitelisted value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How can I check if `$something['say']` has the value of `'bla'` or `'omg'`?

```
$something = array('say' => 'bla', 'say' => 'omg');
```

Comment: The keys in an array must be unique.

Comment: This impossible input makes this page an unattractive canonical for this topic.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Using the instruction `if`?

```
if(isset($something['say']) && $something['say'] === 'bla') {
    // do something
}
```

By the way, you are assigning a value with the key `say` twice, hence your array will result in an array with only one value.

Answer (score 367):

You could use the PHP [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
if(in_array("bla", $yourarray))
{
    echo "has bla";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have an array with identical keys?  Wouldn't the second value overwrite the original?

Comment: I recommend using strict mode instead by adding "true" here: `if( in_array( "bla" ,$yourarray, true)) `

Answer (score 66):

**Using:** `in_array()`

```
$search_array = array('user_from', 'lucky_draw_id', 'prize_id');

if (in_array('prize_id', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'prize_id' element is in the array";
}
```

**Here is the output:**  `The 'prize_id' element is in the array`

---

**Using:** `array_key_exists()`

```
$search_array = array('user_from', 'lucky_draw_id', 'prize_id');

if (array_key_exists('prize_id', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'prize_id' element is in the array";
}
```

**No output**

---

In conclusion, `array_key_exists()` does not work with a simple array. It’s only to find whether an array key exist or not. Use `in_array()` instead.

**Here are more examples:**

```
<?php
/**++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * 1. Example with an associative array using in_array
 *
 * IMPORTANT NOTE: in_array is case-sensitive
 * in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
 *
 * DOES NOT WORK FOR MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */
$something = array('a' => 'bla', 'b' => 'omg');
if (in_array('omg', $something)) {
    echo "|1| The 'omg' value found in the associative array ||";
}

/**++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * 2. Example with an index array using in_array
 *
 * IMPORTANT NOTE: in_array is case-sensitive
 * in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
 *
 * DOES NOT WORK FOR A MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */
$something = array('bla', 'omg');
if (in_array('omg', $something)) {
    echo "|2| The 'omg' value found in the index array ||";
}

/**++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * 3. trying with array_search
 *
 * array_search — Searches the array for a given value
 * and returns the corresponding key if successful
 *
 * DOES NOT WORK FOR MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */
$something = array('a' => 'bla', 'b' => 'omg');
if (array_search('bla', $something)) {
    echo "|3| The 'bla' value found in the assoc array ||";
}

/**++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * 4. trying with isset (fastest ever)
 *
 * isset — Determine if a variable is set and
 * is not NULL
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 */
$something = array('a' => 'bla', 'b' => 'omg');
if($something['a']=='bla'){
    echo "|4| Yeah!! 'bla' found in array ||";
}

/**
 * OUTPUT:
 * |1| The 'omg' element value found in the assoc array ||
 * |2| The 'omg' element value found in the index array ||
 * |3| The 'bla' element value found in the assoc array ||
 * |4| Yeah!! 'bla' found in array ||
 */
?>
```

Here is [a PHP demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4am6-ihgn).

Comment: `array_key_exists()` checks for array keys while the latter `$search_array` contains associative array. No doubt it won't work. You should `array_flip()` it first.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

- [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- a combination of `array_flip()` and `array_key_exists()`

Comment: This appears to just repeat solutions already provided by others years prior.

Answer (score 9):

in_array() is fine if you're only checking, but if you need to check that a value exists and return the associated key, array_search is a better option.

```
$data = [
    'hello',
    'world'
];

$key = array_search('world', $data);

if ($key !== false) {
    echo 'Key is ' . $key;
} else {
    echo 'Key not found';
}
```

This will print "Key is 1".

Answer (score 5):

To check if the index is defined: `isset($something['say'])`

Comment: I don't understand the intent of this answer.  How does achieve the objective of checking an index's value?

Comment: Good question.  This doesn't answer the question at all, as it's written. I don't recall, but since i answered about 3 minutes after the question was originally asked, i'd guess that the OP edited their original question to make it more clear, within the initial edit cutoff before it gets registered as an edit. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @echo No, any answer or edit to the question by another user will immediately end the grace period afforded to users where edits don't get publicly recorded.

Comment: Perhaps, but was that the case in 2010?  Who knows.

Answer (score 5):

You can test whether an array has a certain element at all or not with [isset()](http://docs.php.net/isset) or sometimes even better [array_key_exists()](http://docs.php.net/array_key_exists) (the documentation explains the differences). If you can't be sure if the array has an element with the index 'say' you should test that first or you might get 'warning: undefined index....' messages.

As for the test whether the element's value is equal to a string you can use == or (again sometimes better) the identity operator [===](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.comparison) which doesn't allow [type juggling](http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling).

```
if( isset($something['say']) && 'bla'===$something['say'] ) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the PHP function `array_key_exists()`

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (in_array('your_variable', $Your_array)) {
    $redImg = 'true code here';
} else {
    $redImg = 'false code here';
} 
?>
```

Comment: A better answer *usually* contains an explanation in addition to the code. I believe doing so will improve your answer!

Comment: This is already suggested in the highest-voted answer.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

**Another use of in_array**
 **in_array() with an array as needle**

```
<?php
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}

if (in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a)) {
    echo "'fi' was found\n";
}

if (in_array('o', $a)) {
    echo "'o' was found\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"an array as needle"*?

Comment: means using an array as the value you're searching for within another array.

in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a) checks if the array array('p', 'h') exists within the array $a. It looks for the exact match of the sub-array array('p', 'h') within the multidimensional array $a. In this case, it finds it and echoes "'ph' was found".

in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a) checks if the array array('f', 'i') exists within the array $a. However, this sub-array does not exist within $a, so it does not echo "'fi' was found".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a simple array, i.e.

```
$MyArray = array("red","blue","green");
```

You can use this function

```
function val_in_arr($val,$arr){
  foreach($arr as $arr_val){
    if($arr_val == $val){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
val_in_arr("red",$MyArray); //returns true
val_in_arr("brown",$MyArray); //returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

An associative array can only have a key defined once, so this array would never exist. Otherwise, just use `in_array()` to determine if that specific array element is in an array of possible solutions.