# check if one value exists in an array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an array value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

I have a problem in PHP. So, my problem is that I want to see if a particular value exists in a session (in which session I store an array). And if this value exists to return me a boolean ($check=TRUE). But when I try to stop the script with die (var_dump($check)); in  order to check the value, I get always this notice:

> Undefined variable check...

This is my code:

```
 $individualitem[] = $_SESSION["books"] ;

          foreach ($individualitem as $key => $idividualvalue){
            if($individualitem == $card){
                $check = TRUE;
            }     
         }  
     // die (var_dump($check));
```

Comment: Even if you are very new to php you should [do research before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists). When you [type your exact question title into google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=check+if+one+value+exists+in+an+array), you'll get the answer immediately. We like to answer your questions, but we dont like to answer duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the if condition is always false. Defined your $check before the actual foreach loop

```
$check = false;  
foreach ($individualitem as $key => $idividualvalue){
     if($individualitem == $card){
         $check = TRUE;
     }     
}
```

But for your purpose, try

```
$check = false;
if (in_array($card, $individualitem)) {
    $check = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if contition is apperently never met, try defaulting `$check` to false.

```
$individualitem[] = $_SESSION["books"] ;
$check = false;
foreach ($individualitem as $key => $idividualvalue)
{
    if($individualitem == $card)
    {
        $check = true;
    }     
}  
     // die (var_dump($check));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try php's inbuilt function [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: It doesn't tell him why is it throwing a notice

Comment: but it is indeed a better way to get his task done.