# i don't know how to check if a value is in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => comments
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => approve
                    [1] => delete
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => users
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => info
                    [1] => ban
                )

        )

)
```

i've this array. I want to check if this user group has these permissions. In this array there are two other array. The first one is the category, while the second one is the array that contains the actions connected to that section. For example: i'm in this group, so i can see "comments" section in the admin panel and i can approve and delete comments, but i can't edit comments because this action isn't in the array. ok i know it's a bit difficult to understand, but i need your help. (im italian) <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array value exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest for your sanity to use *named* array keys rather than numberic ones.

Then in would use the PHP manual for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.in-array.php)

so you can do something like this:

```
$myArray = <your original array>;

foreach($myArray as $row){  
    if(in_array("delete",$row[1])){
       print "Delete is in array. you can edit ".$row[0][0];
    } 
}
unset($row);
```

**Output:**

```
 Delete is in array. you can edit comments.
  //no output for array "users" as can't delete users.
```

Answer (score 0):

A small recursive function like this might be handy. It checks if sub-element is array.

```
function checkarrayRec($array,$permissions=["info","ban","delete","approve"]) {
    if(is_array($array)) {
        foreach($array as $key => $a) {
            if(is_array($a)) {
            checkarrayRec($a);
            } else {
            if(!empty($a) and in_array($a,$permissions)) {
               echo "Found: ".$a."\n";
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
$array = [[[0,1],[1,2]],[[3,4],["delete","approve"]]];
checkarrayRec($array) ;
// output is 
Found: delete
Found: approve
```

Check it on [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5a7a692335b1f659047c4ebf708717f1c4e129c)

Answer (score 0):

To check whether something is an element of an array, you need to use the function `in_array` - this takes two parameters, the first of which is the element that you want to check for, the second is the array itself.

From your explanation, you have three nested arrays, that is to say, an array inside an array inside an array.

The first index is provided, since this is that of the user.
From $myarray[userId] we then have two nested arrays - an array inside an array, with the index known, since there are always two in each category. There are two possible cases here:

1. You want to find if a value is in *any* of the categories.
2. You want to find if a value is in *a particular one* of the categories.

Due to the structure, both of these will require you to iterate over the arrays. Finding if a permission is in a specific category will just take an additional check within the loop.

Finding if a permission is in any of the categories:

```
foreach ($myArray[$userId] as $permissionCategory) {
    return in_array("permission", $permissionCategory[1]);
}
return false;
```

Finding if a permission is in a specific category:

```
foreach ($myArray[$userId] as $permissionCategory) {
    if ($permissionCategory[0][0] == "category") {
        return in_array("permission", $permissionCategory[1]);
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The help of Martin works... only problem is i don't know the array number (in_array("delete",$row[1]). indeed i have this string that defines the permissions of a particular group to which users belong: comments:approve,delete|users:info,ban

This string is converted to array through an explode which removes " / : , "
Then we'll have:
comments -> PERMISSIONS CONNECTED TO THIS CAT: approve delete
users -> PERMISSIONS CONNECTED TO THIS CAT: info (see user info) ban (ban user)

But i can add other elements in the string, so i can't know the array number.

Comment: You can use various function to walk through each element in an array, such as `array_map` or `foreach` . It sounds like you need to structure your data a little more.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
    if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
        echo "Got Irix";
    }
    elseif (in_array("mac", $os)) {
        echo "Got mac";
    }
    else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: this does very little to help the OP