# Search for Specific Text with Special Characters in a String in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, search

I am using a script to check if a string **$status** (randomly generated from another script which is interacting with an API) contains the following text(s) or not -

**SC-102**

**EOD-103**

**EOD-31**

**DLYDC-104**

**EOD-72**

**ST-108**

**SC-104**

**X-SC**

**EOD-114**

**DLYMR-118**

**EOD-76**

**EOD-6**

**EOD-95**

**EOD-69**

**EOD-16**

**EOD-2**
**EOD-97**

**EOD-110**

**EOD-15**

**EOD-32**

**EOD-107**

**EOD-106**

**EOD-46**

**EOD-104**

**EOD-42**

**EOD-7**

**EOD-111**

**EOD-43**

> Can I use **OR** or **||** in my code ?

The **Letters, Special Characters & Numbers**  are one single piece of TEXT.
For. Example - **ST-102** is an exact text to be search from ***$status***

My present code looks like the following -

```
$codes = array("SC-102","EOD-103","EOD-31","DLYDC-104","EOD-72","ST-108","SC-104","X-SC","EOD-114","DLYMR-118","EOD-76","EOD-6","EOD-95","EOD-69","EOD-16","EOD-2","EOD-97","EOD-110","EOD-15","EOD-32","EOD-107","EOD-106","EOD-46","EOD-104","EOD-42","EOD-7","EOD-111","EOD-43");

if($status_code==$codes)
{
//My Script , if condition is true!
}
```

Comment: use `in_array()` function. `if(in_array($status_code, $codes)){ // your script }`

Comment: @FrayneKonok

Please share the code, I'm getting error. I've tried that also.

The problem is that the search text is in VARCHAR format, If I'm not wrong.

I've done the same code previously which was successful but with only plain text

Comment: I share my script, But I can't fetch any problem. can you please clear it a little more?

Comment: Where are you stuck to understand ?

Comment: This is really bad news to me, the same script shared by me but not accepted, But 10 min less answer accepted.

There is no meaning of early answer and early responses...

Comment: @FrayneKonok Please check your answer and Rishi's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147902/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-alpha).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array value exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` and `in_array` function to achieve

```
<?php
    $string = 'SC-102 || EOD-103 || EOD-31 || DLYDC-104 || EOD-72 || ST-108 || SC-104 || X-SC || EOD-114 || DLYMR-118 || EOD-76 || EOD-6 || EOD-95 || EOD-69 || EOD-16 || EOD-2 || EOD-97 || EOD-110 || EOD-15 || EOD-32 || EOD-107 || EOD-106 || EOD-46 || EOD-104 || EOD-42 || EOD-7 || EOD-111 || EOD-43';
    $codes = explode(' || ',$string);

    $status_code = 'ST-108';
    if(in_array($status_code, $codes)){ 
        echo "Code Found\n";
    }else{
        echo "Code Not Found\n";
    }

    $status_code = 'ST-102';
    if(in_array($status_code, $codes)){ 
        echo "Code Found\n";
    }else{
        echo "Code Not Found\n";
    }
?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/824205

Comment: @lalithkumar it may be a duplicate method, but this post is presented much more intelligently (better formatted / easier to read) and has not been hastily / sloppily posted, edited, deleted, undeleted, deleted, undeleted, edited, edited, etc.  Perhaps the OP would look at your answer if you didn't keep changing it.  Next time don't be so hasty to post an answer -- quality is what earns the most rep points in the long run.

Comment: @Alpha You clearly don't know what you want/need and you are wasting the time of all of these volunteers.  Please update your question immediately.

Comment: $statuses = "SC-102 || EOD-103 || EOD-31 || DLYDC-104 || EOD-72 || ST-108 || SC-104 || X-SC || EOD-114 || DLYMR-118 || EOD-76 || EOD-6 || EOD-95 || EOD-69 || EOD-16 || EOD-2 || EOD-97 || EOD-110 || EOD-15 || EOD-32 || EOD-107 || EOD-106 || EOD-46 || EOD-104 || EOD-42 || EOD-7 || EOD-111 || EOD-43";

I'm using **"** instead of **'**

Comment: @mickmackusa resolved thanks! Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    $codes = array("SC-102","EOD-103","EOD-31","DLYDC-104","EOD-72","ST-108","SC-104","X-SC","EOD-114","DLYMR-118","EOD-76","EOD-6","EOD-95","EOD-69","EOD-16","EOD-2","EOD-97","EOD-110","EOD-15","EOD-32","EOD-107","EOD-106","EOD-46","EOD-104","EOD-42","EOD-7","EOD-111","EOD-43");
    $status_code = 'ST-108';
    if(in_array($status_code,$codes))
    {
    //My Script , if condition is true!
    }
```

I thing it will help you .You can Check [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

**Edit:-**
Just change your if statement to

```
if(in_array($status_code,$codes))
```

Comment: I want to search for all the codes specified in the array!

$status_code is a value fetched from the database, it cannot be predefined.

Comment: Okay the data is a string or array ?If string the assign the value in $staus_code variable.

Comment: Couldn't get you ?

Answer (score 0):

you can search one value whether that exist in array or not.When you have string with || then you need to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and then use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).Try below:

```
$values="SC-102 || EOD-103 || EOD-31 || DLYDC-104 || EOD-72 || ST-108 || SC-104 || X-SC || EOD-114 || DLYMR-118 || EOD-76 || EOD-6 || EOD-95 || EOD-69 || EOD-16 || EOD-2 || EOD-97 || EOD-110 || EOD-15 || EOD-32 || EOD-107 || EOD-106 || EOD-46 || EOD-104 || EOD-42 || EOD-7 || EOD-111 || EOD-43";
$codearr=explode("||",$values);
foreach($codearr as $status_code){
if(in_array($status_code,$codes)){
//found
}
else{
//not found
}
}
```

Comment: did you try this ? @Alpha

Comment: Is it 
explode(" || ",$values)

OR

explode("||", $values);

With spaces around || or without ?

Comment: however in the string

Comment: Didn't try with foreach!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the given script-

```
$codes = array("SC-102","EOD-103","EOD-31","DLYDC-104","EOD-72","ST-108","SC-104","X-SC","EOD-114","DLYMR-118","EOD-76","EOD-6","EOD-95","EOD-69","EOD-16","EOD-2","EOD-97","EOD-110","EOD-15","EOD-32","EOD-107","EOD-106","EOD-46","EOD-104","EOD-42","EOD-7","EOD-111","EOD-43");

$status_code = 'ST-108';
if(in_array($status_code, $codes)){ 
    echo 'Found';
}else 
    echo 'Not Found';
```

Comment: What about the `$status_code`?? If you need to search for all the values then you can use loop

Comment: Loop as in , how ?

Loop for every individual status ?

Comment: Your goal is not clear, but from your given script the answer should be the answer or with loop with individual status.

Comment: The below code works because it is simply numeric 
(I'm using this below code in an existing script and it is working)

if($status_code == (221 || 222 || 223 || 224 || 227 || 228 || 307 || 331 || 218 || 219 || 220))
{
//Run Script ,if found
}

My point is , can we use OR or || to do this ?

Comment: @Alpha, in php, no, you can't do it like that.

Comment: Did you try my script yet?? Is there any problem with `in_array()`, The function will perform the same thing you are looking for...