# PHP: Comparison of array value not working?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to comparing array value, if value found `if(isset($row['height']) == ['3455'])` then print the array value but it is not working it is return all the array which includes not matching value too.
How will I compare a value and **if value found then print that single value of array not all value**.

Here is my **print_r value**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Bradeley Hall Pool
            [postcode] => CW1 5QN
            [lat] => 53.10213
            [lon] => -2.41069
            [size] => 1.60
            [pegs] => 21
            [distance] => 26.6
            [suitability] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [species] => Barbel
                            [species] => 1
                            [record] => 1
                            [weight] => 2.721554
                            [length] => 40
                            [height] => ['abc','345m','3455']
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Farm Pool
            [postcode] => CW9 6JQ
            [lat] => 53.320502
            [lon] => -2.549049
            [size] => 0.88
            [pegs] => 8
            [distance] => 15.4
            [suitability] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [species] => Barbel
                            [species] => 1
                            [record] => 1
                            [weight] => 2.721554
                            [length] => 40
                            [height] => ['33','3455','3mnc']
                        )
                )
       )
)
```

**My code -**

```
foreach( $cursor as $row){
 
    foreach ($row['suitability'] as  $item) {
  
        if(isset($item['height']) == ['3455']){
            echo 'yes';
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($item['height']);
        } else{
            echo 'no';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean (TRUE or FALSE) So it will never equal an array containing one item of anything

Comment: If you want to check if a value is in an array - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists.

Comment: How will I compare then because it is giving me error `Undefined index: height `  also in some cases **height array** contains single value too rather than multiple array

Comment: @RiggsFolly [Well, technically, it can](https://3v4l.org/DNsUj), due to the weird conversions PHP does for non-strict comparisons :) (I don't mean this makes any sense to do it, but just saying.)

Comment: Also you dont have a `$row['height']` but you may have an `$item['height']`

Comment: Do you expect the height array to be messed up? Your examples do not match.

Comment: I have updated Please check

Comment: @NigelRen examples are not useful I am still trying help!

Comment: If examples are not useful, how are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most obvious issue may be that `[height] => ['abc','345m','3455']` is not an array, otherwise the `print_r()` would have shown it as one. So it must be a string.

So this would work

```
foreach( $cursor as $row){
    foreach ($row['suitability'] as $suit) {
        // can we find the string in there somewhere
        if (strpos($suit['height'], '3455') !== false) {
            echo 'yes  ';
            echo $suit['height'];
            echo PHP_EOL;
        } else{
            echo 'no';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are shorter ways, but you should use `isset` to check for the existence of the array key. Once you know it is present, you can `in_array` to check for a specific value within the `height` array.

```
<?php
foreach($cursor as $row){

    // Check if the row has the key `suitability`.
    if (isset($row['suitability'])) {

        foreach ($row['suitability'] as $item) {


            // Check if the item has the key `height`.
            if (isset($item['height'])) {

                 // Assuming `height` is always an array.
                 if (in_array('3455', $item['height']) {
                     // Yes.
                 }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: it is not working not giving error `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array`

Comment: In your examples (`[height] => ['abc','345m','3455']`) _height_ is an array. Is it sometimes not an array?