# Use comma separated string to create or statements in if else?

Tags: php

Currently, I have this piece of code that works fine.

```php
if ($ext == 'jpg' or $ext == 'gif' or $ext == 'png' or $ext == 'jpeg' or $ext == 'eps' or $ext == 'pdf') {
  // Extension found execute the rest.
} else {
  // Extension not found show a warning or something.
}
```

But this is what I call hard coded, and I would like the end user to be able to change it in the settings of the component where this code is a part of.
In these settings I can quite easily create an input where the user then needs to fill in a comma separated list with all the extension they want.

In this case: `jpg,gif,png,jpeg,eps,pdf`

These settings will then be retrieved like: `$ext = $setting_extensions` which shows a string `jpg,gif,png,jpeg,eps,pdf`

**But how can this be used inside this if statement?**

I guess I can use explode and foreach:

```php
$tests = explode(",", $ext);
foreach($tests as $test) {

}
```

But how do I get it inside this if statement with the or?

Comment: `explode` and `in_array`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an array value exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

Comment: @El_Vanja After receiving the answers from the contributors and reading your suggestion again I can now see how it can answer my question (have to test first though) but before that I could not see how it was applicable. But thank you for suggesting the question as I did not search for those keywords before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in_array for that.

```
$tests = explode(",", $setting_extensions);
if (in_array($ext, $tests)) {
   // Extension found execute the rest.
} else {
  // Extension not found show a warning or something.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I am going to try this out as well as the other answers and I will accept an answer a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `in_array()` function within your `if` statement's conditions:

```
$tests = explode(',', $extString);

if (in_array($ext, $tests))) {
    // success
}
```

But I would also add in some normalization, so capitalization, spacing, etc, doesn't become a factor:

```
$tests = explode(',', $extString);
$tests = array_map(function($test) {
    return strtolower(trim($test))
}, $tests); 

if (in_array(strtolower($ext), $tests)) {
    // success
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I am going to try this out as well as the other answers and I will accept an answer a.s.a.p.