# How to check if an array contains valid MySQL data types?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with mysql data types. E.g.

```
$dataTypes = array("VARCHAR(1000)", "DATE", "DATETIME");
```

Is there an easy way to validate that the data types are valid? The MySQL version can be ignored.

Or is there a way to run a query to check if a data type is valid?

Comment: check with what?

Comment: With PHP (or JavaScript)

Comment: make a list of all data types which you consider valid (your find them in the docs), then use in_array or preg_match etc

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an array value exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

Comment: The question ist not how to verify if a value exists in an array. It's about find out if the values in the array are valid MySQL types. E.g. VARCHAR(1000) is valid, VARCHAR() wouldn't be.