# PHP Syntax Error when trying to use a function

Tags: php

Recently I started working with PHP and creating functions to make stuff easier for me.

I just created a simple function that I can use in a lot of files so it checks the users 'permission group' (e.g. Admin).

This is the code that was used:

```
function staffCheckStart() {
    echo "if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin' OR $_SESSION['role'] == 'Owner'):";
}

function staffCheckEnd() {
    echo "endif";
}
```

This is how the function is called in another document.

```
<?php staffCheckStart(); ?>
        
   <iframe src="gif.com" width="276" height="480" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="gif.com">via GIPHY</a></p>

<?php staffCheckEnd(); ?>
```

And in return I get [this](https://gyazo.com/bc8e84079bda01f6f2c9857edd27d1ff) error.

In my head this all works out because I just want the code to *echo* the PHP line that I've written in my function.
The only reason I tried to use functions is because I first of all want to make it easier and make the code look clean as writing things like [this](https://gyazo.com/213cb96d770d34b4a468b5783cc4ef38) over and over really drives me insane.
It returns me a syntax error but I have no clue what it is.

Comment: And which line is the error referring to?  Also, this won't work *at all*.  You're trying to echo PHP code to the browser, but the browser doesn't execute PHP code.  PHP code needs to be executed on the server, not output to the browser as a string.

Comment: Echoing an `if` statement will not cause the statement to be execute.

Comment: Just use [`in_array()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440506/how-to-check-if-an-array-value-exists)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't echo PHP code to browser to work, it just make code like string.
Second, from what I saw in your code, I think you want show  `iframe` when role is "Admin" or "Owner". So, I suggest you to make like this

```php
<?php if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin' OR $_SESSION['role'] == 'Owner'): ?>
        
   <iframe src="gif.com" width="276" height="480" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="gif.com">via GIPHY</a></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing PHP code will not substitute the code back into the script to be executed. So your whole approach is misguided.

The function should return the result of the condition, and then you can call it in an ordinary `if` statement.

```
<?php
function staffCheck() {
    return $_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin' OR $_SESSION['role'] == 'Owner';
}

if ($staffCheck()): ?>
   <iframe src="gif.com" width="276" height="480" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="gif.com">via GIPHY</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```